# What's the oldest OS Java 8 supports?

Tags: java, java-8, jvm, minimum-requirements, minimumosversion

I'm writing some software in Java 8 and I want to know how to write the minimum requirements for the product page, so its users know if it'll work for them before they try to use it.

For example, I know Java was, at some point, supported on Windows XP and OS X Lion, but I'm not sure about older versions of those, or the oldest Linux (shell?) version that supports it.

Also, I suspect there are other reasons I shouldn't try to make my software support these OSs, and if those reasons are specific to running Java 8 on them, I'm all ears!

**What are the oldest operating systems that my Java 8 SE software will run on?**

Comment: Let me put it this way: if Microsoft is not even supporting Windows XP anymore, why should you?

Comment: @JoeC if the support comes for free (I'm not currently doing anything platform-dependent or outside the SE library), then why not?

Comment: Java was designed to run platform-independent programs.

Comment: @MonkeySupersonic yes, I know. That's why I'm using it! But sometimes you want to know the OS, for instance when skinning it to make it look more native.

Comment: supported? no. works? maybe. this was the 3rd google result for me: https://blogs.oracle.com/henrik/entry/the_future_of_java_on

Comment: also note that oracle is not the only JVM vendor.

Comment: @the8472 great point! I'd love some arguments for others, but this is a general library, and I assume the general user just uses Oracle's JRE from java.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should run on any OS that support Java 8. According to [Oracle](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/sysreq.xml), Minimum requirements as follows.

**Windows**

- Windows 10 (8u51 and above)
- Windows 8.x (Desktop)
- Windows 7 SP1
- Windows Vista SP2
- Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 (64-bit)
- Windows Server 2012 and 2012 R2 (64-bit)

(*RAM*: 128 MB
*Disk space*: 124 MB for JRE; 2 MB for Java Update,
*Processor*: Minimum Pentium 2 266 MHz processor,
*Browsers*: Internet Explorer 9 and above, Firefox)

**Mac OS X**

- Intel-based Mac running Mac OS X 10.8.3+, 10.9+

(Administrator privileges for installation, 64-bit browser, A 64-bit browser (Safari, for example) is required to run Oracle Java on Mac. )

**Linux**

- Oracle Linux 5.5+1
- Oracle Linux 6.x (32-bit), 6.x (64-bit)2
- Oracle Linux 7.x (64-bit)2 (8u20 and above)
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.5+1, 6.x (32-bit), 6.x (64-bit)2
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.x (64-bit)2 (8u20 and above)
- Suse Linux Enterprise Server 10 SP2+, 11.x
- Suse Linux Enterprise Server 12.x (64-bit)2 (8u31 and above)
- Ubuntu Linux 12.04 LTS, 13.x
- Ubuntu Linux 14.x (8u25 and above)
- Ubuntu Linux 15.04 (8u45 and above)
- Ubuntu Linux 15.10 (8u65 and above)

(Browsers: Firefox )

Comment: In other words: There is no way to affect the compatibility between program and OS since this is exactly the purpose of the Java VM.

Answer (score 1):

It should run on any OS that support Java 8. According to Oracle, Changes the Minimum requirements as follows.

Windows

```
Windows 10 (8u51 and above)
Windows 8.x (Desktop)
Windows 7
Windows Vista
Windows XP
Windows 2000 
Windows Server 2012 and 2012 R2
Windows Server 2008 R2
Windows Server 2008
Windows Server 2003
```

(RAM: 128 MB Disk space: 124 MB for JRE; 2 MB for Java Update, Processor: Minimum Pentium 2 266 MHz processor, Browsers: Internet Explorer 6 and above, Firefox)

Mac OS X

```
Intel-based Mac running Mac OSX 9. and highter
```

(Administrator privileges for installation, all browser, all browser (Safari, for example) is required to run Oracle Java on Mac. )

Linux

```
Oracle Linux 5.5+1
Oracle Linux 6.x (32-bit), 6.x (64-bit)2
Oracle Linux 7.x (64-bit)2 (8u20 and above)
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.5+1, 6.x (32-bit), 6.x (64-bit)2
Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.x (64-bit)2 (8u20 and above)
Suse Linux Enterprise Server 10 SP2+, 11.x
Suse Linux Enterprise Server 12.x (64-bit)2 (8u31 and above)
Ubuntu Linux 12.04 LTS, 13.x
Ubuntu Linux 14.x (8u25 and above)
Ubuntu Linux 15.04 (8u45 and above)
Ubuntu Linux 15.10 (8u65 and above)
Debian Linux 5
```

(Browsers: Firefox,... )